# Personal Portfolio Page - Stuck with Bootstrap Grid Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

https://codepen.io/shaan046/pen/vWmVNY

HTML code:

```
<body>
  <div id="header" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1"><h3 id="myText">Shantanu Tomar</h3</div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-2 col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-2"><button class="btn btn-primary">Button1</button></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button class="btn">Button2</button></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button class="btn">Button3</button></div>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
#header{
  background-color:red;
}
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").addClass("container-fluid");

});
```

What I want is that the text “Shantanu Tomar” and 3 buttons on screen should come in `div #header` in a single row. I am using Bootstrap3. Not sure how I can provide `col--` tags so that the webpage is visible on Phone, tablet, Laptop in right manner? I tried using `lg` and `md` classes but the buttons are not lining up with text “Shantanu Tomar”.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: check this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KymJYx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. and learn bootstrap from W3schools https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

```html
<html>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div id="header" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <h3 id="myText">Shantanu Tomar</h3></div>
        <div class=" col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button class="btn btn-primary">Button1</button></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button class="btn">Button2</button></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button class="btn">Button3</button></div>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried but its the same. Actually what i am not sure here is that why did you specify a div with col-md-12 and col-lg-12. By default, we have that set as 12 and we can span out of that 12 columns as per our convenience. Please correct me if i am wrong ?

Comment: Thanks for it.. It worked :) But I still don't get it why i need to make a different div for it. By default it is 12 ?

Comment: Yeah by default it takes columns no need to add `col-lg-12` there but for styling(it adds 15px padding) i used it. you may replace it with `row` sorry for my above comment. removed it

Comment: Change `col-md-*` values as your wish. I think you miss the closing of `h3` tag so you got output like that. check that once

Comment: Thanks. How can i remove the padding space in between buttons here so that my text is on the left hand side .. and then i have my 3 buttons with small space in between on the right hand side ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158836/discussion-between-znaneswar-and-shantanu-tomar).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `col-xs-3` *(since you have four elements)* if you want the elements to be in a single row, and no need for jquery here.

```css
#header {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="header" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <h3 id="myText">Shantanu Tomar</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <button class="btn">Button2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <button class="btn">Button3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but not resolved. I believe xs is for Phone devices. If i am viewing it on laptop it will not render in right manner as for that we have other tags like lg and md.

Comment: Using `xs` means that starting from the lowest width possible up to the highest width possible, it will always have 12 columns. I don't know about you but it is working in my machine, it is still in a single row

Comment: ^ It should be *always have 3 columns* rather than 12

Answer (score -2):

Why do not use a `<ul>` ?

Something like this :

```html
<div id="header" class="row">
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><button class="btn btn-primary">Button1</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn btn-primary">Button2</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn btn-primary">Button3</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please note, I want to make use of Bootstrap grid layout approach.